# React component is not returning fetched data from the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

So i recently had an issue of api is not fetching the data. But when i get that fixed, now there is a another problem of component is not returning anything that the api is fetching. Here is the code of the component.

```
import React from 'react';
import  { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Content=(api)=>{

  const [cities, setItems] = useState([]);

  // const API=api;
  console.log(api);
  console.log(cities)

  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(api){
        fetch(api)
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then(result => {
                // add some guarding condition here for result
                let updatedCities = cities.concat(result);
                console.log(cities)
                setItems(updatedCities);
           })
    }
  },[api]);


    return (
        <ul>
          <h4>hello</h4>
        {cities.map(citi => (
          <li key={citi.city.id}>
            The city is is{citi.city.id} 
            The city name is{citi.city.name}
            The temparature is {citi.list[0].main.temp}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
  
      
    )
  }


export default Content;
```

API is updating each time when changes a city. And the component should re-render each time the API changes.

and the output is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDUmA.png) As you can see api is fetching data but the array is empty when it tries to map the array.how to fix that.

p.s when i replace the api in the useEffect with a fixed API(Without any parameters), the component works perfectly fine.

Here is the code of the serchbar component. Where the api is being updated

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import Cities from './citylist';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Content from './content';


const SearchBar=()=>{

  const [city,setcity]=useState("");
  const [api,setapi]=useState(``);
  
 

    const apiFtecher = e => {
      const city =(e.target.value);
      console.log(city);
      return (
       setapi(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city},LK&mode=json&appid=5c4420d5c8a61c16e5ee37e4ca265763`)
       );
     }

     Content(api); 

    return (
        <div style={{ width: 300 }}>
      <Autocomplete
        freeSolo
        id="free-solo-2-demo"
        disableClearable
        options={Cities.map((option) => option.name)} 
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="city"
            margin="normal"
            variant="outlined"
            InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, type: 'search' }}
            // onChange={apiFtecher}
            onBlur={apiFtecher}
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
    );

}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: First thing I see is that you should get you `api` prop by writing `const Content = ({api}) =>{...} ` (With brakets), else it means you are retrieving all of the props inside `api` and would need to write `api.api`.

Comment: @QuentinGrisel i tried both ways.non of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a problem with the way you are calling your `Content` component. You should put it inside the return of your `searchbar` component, especially if you want it to return jsx and pass your api data.

```
const SearchBar=()=>{
  ...
  return (
    {Content(api)};
  );
}
```

Note that if your `Content` function is supposed to be called as a component, then you will need to change the way you are retrieving your props by wrapping api, as follow :

`const Content = ({api}) =>{...}`